# Python pyramid with 2 different symbols

Tags: python

How to print a pyramid in python with 2 different symbols?

For example,

```
    #
    $ $
    # # #
    $ $ $ $
    # # # # #
```

Comment: Yes, it is easy. Show your efforts first.

Comment: I know to print the pyramid with a single symbol   def pypart(n):
     
    
    for i in range(0, n):
     
        
        for j in range(0, i+1):
         
            print("* ",end="")
      
        print("\r")
 
n = 5
pypart(n)

Comment: Yes, but if you show us your efforts. We might be able to point you in the right direction if got stuck or better your code in some way if we can :)

Comment: I have no idea with 2 symbols

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, regardless of python version:

```
def pyramid(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                print '# ',
            else:
                print '$ ',
        print '\r'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop.

```
side = 4
for i in range(side):
    for j in range(i):
        if i%2==0:
            print("#",end="")
        else:
            print("$",end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Please don't encourage low effort questions. This is obviously homework. Do you want someone else to get a grade by showing code you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in your comment:

```
def pypart(n):
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            symbol = '# ' if i % 2 == 0 else '$ '
            print(symbol, end="")
        print("\r")

n = 5
pypart(n)

> #
> $ $
> # # #
> $ $ $ $
> # # # # #
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bit more customization (and maybe a bit of motivation to read on list comprehensions).

```
def slope(lvl = 5, symbols = ['#', '$']):
    symbols_ = symbols * (lvl // len(symbols)) + symbols[0:(lvl % len(symbols))]
    return '\n'.join([x*y for y, x in zip(range(1,lvl+1), symbols_)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(slope())
    # prints:
    # #
    # $$
    # ###
    # $$$$
    # #####

    print(slope(10, ['#', '$', '*']))
    # prints
    # #
    # $$
    # ***
    # ####
    # $$$$$
    # ******
    # #######
    # $$$$$$$$
    # *********
    # ##########
```